# Is an advantage for a left-handed to play volleyball?

Tags: technique, volleyball

Are there any objective advantages to a left-handed in playing volleyball?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some advantages for right-hand side players (setters and opposites): in the same way that it's easier for a right-hander to hit down the line from the left-hand side of the court, it's easier for a left-hander to hit line from the right-hand side of the court. In particular, if the setter wants to do a surprise hit rather than setting the ball, they almost have to hit it left-handed - there's no real way to create deception with a right-handed hit. There's a good video of left-handed hitters [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P1CS5jyA_-I) - as you'll see, almost all the hits are from the right-hand side rather than the left-hand side ([Uroš Kovačević](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uro%C5%A1_Kova%C4%8Devi%C4%87) being the exception).

That said, a fair number of the best opposites in the world ([Wallace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace_de_Souza), [Bartosz Kurek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartosz_Kurek), [Matt Anderson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Anderson_(volleyball)), [Ivan Zaytsev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Zaytsev_(volleyball)), et al) are right handed.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find a research by Psychonomic Society from 2011 ["On the advantage of being left-handed in volleyball: further evidence of the specificity of skilled visual perception"](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/s13414-011-0252-1.pdf), which has the following conclusion:

> [...] findings indicating side-specific visual perception support the
>   assumption that the orientation of action presentation has a
>   considerable influence on athletes’ anticipation performance in
>   interactive sporting situations. Even at the early developmental
>   stages of perceptual expertise, highly specific adaptations occur to
>   the cognitive system, and after years of practice, these adaptations
>   become highly specific (Ericsson & Lehmann, 1996). [...]